# What's the recommended approach to generating a Preview Thumbnail Image of the fist page of a FlowDocument

Tags: .net, wpf, flowdocument

I would like to generate a small Preview Image of the fist page of a FlowDocument (imagine a Thumbnail View of a collection of FlowDocuments). Can anyone recommend a good approach for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by making your FlowDocument display the first page as you want it to appear in the thumbnail, then pointing a RenderTargetBitmap to the FlowDocument and saving the bitmap to disk. There is some code to do this in this article:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/150676.aspx

Comment: Remember that the size of your flowdocument will have a bearing on how quickly it will load. As such, you may want to pre-generate and cache the bitmap before you end up needing it in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Image magick DLL for generating thumbnail image
see link : http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php
Add reference in your website application to re-size image as thumbnail for eq: 100*100 thumbnail image

1) first you download image magick setup from above link.
2) install in your pc for register DLL in your system
3) Add reference DLL in your website(DLL located in your program files\ImageMagick like that )

example in C# code
/********************************************************************************/

```
ImageMagickObject.MagickImage imgLarge = new ImageMagickObject.MagickImage();
string resizedPara = "100x100"; 
object[] objResize = new object[] { <your saved original image path>, "-resize", size, "-gravity", "center", "-colorspace", "RGB", "-extent", resizedPara , <OutPut Resized Image path> }; 
imgLarge.Convert(ref objResize);
```

/********************************************************************************/
Read the tutorial for resize image in any size and format...
its good to use image magick...

Thanks abhishek